# Making grids in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules

In QGIS I am trying to make a map with the [Maidenhead Locator System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maidenhead_Locator_System) overlayed. I am making these overlays with QGIS's create grid tool but the grids are not coming out right.

If I leave the map unprojected the bigger and smaller grid lines are parallel but any projection I use they are not parallel. Does anybody know how to fix this?

[image: Picture_of_error]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The grid creator makes very simple lines with vertices only on each end. You'll need to 'densify' the geometry (adding extra vertices) so that intermediate points can be projected and define the shape of the lines correctly.

For example, here's an unprojected map with a default grid from QGIS (5° intervals):

[image]

If we change the projection (Aitoff 54043), the lines still render straight but clearly the shape of Africa has changed:

[image]

Using the 'densify by count' tool from processing and adding 50 vertices per line, we get a new grid that seems to curve correctly:

[image]

Editing the vertices of one line of the densified geometry shows how many points define the shape along the way:

[image]